# Filter for each level of multiple variables

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I would like to simulate the act of sifting through a pivot table in excel to find subtle differences in your data frames while keeping certain variables constant. I am struggling to figure out how to accomplish evaluating every level of multiple variables for differences automatically. I do know iterating through data frames is not recommended. See below for details:

Starting DataFrame:

```
 Year  Group1   Group2   Group3   Target
 2015   A        b         X         1
 2016   A        a         Y         0
 2017   C        d         Z         1
 2015   A        b         X         0
 2016   A        d         X         0
 2017   C        d         Z         0
```

Result:

```
 Year  Group1   Group2   Group3   Target
 2015   A        b         X         1
 2015   A        b         X         0
 2017   C        d         Z         1
 2017   C        d         Z         0
```

The result should check each combination of year, group 1, group 2, group 3 and return any rows where there are differences in only the target column for all matches.

I am currently at creating a unique variable for each row by concatenating the fields and then using sort and groupby to go through each manually, but I know there has to be a better way.

```
df['variable'] = df['Year'] + df['Group1'] + df['Group2'] + df['Group3']
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you explain your filter logic as well? Under what conditions do you want to filer out a row?

Comment: Great question! I would want to filter out a row when there is not at least a row with a 1 and a row with a 0 in the target column for that combination of Year, Group1, Group2, and Group3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could benefit from a filtering with `groupby` + `transform`:

```
m = df.groupby(
        ['Year', 'Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3']
).Target.transform('count').gt(1)

df[m].drop_duplicates()

   Year Group1 Group2 Group3  Target
0  2015      A      b      X       1
2  2017      C      d      Z       1
3  2015      A      b      X       0
5  2017      C      d      Z       0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am having a hard time finding it and it is getting me close, but not quite where I want. I still end up with NaN values after I pivot the groupby/transformed dataframe. Can you please explain what 'transform('count').gt(1)' does?

Comment: @JoshJanjua it finds all rows belonging to those groups which have more than one item per group. Try only transform("count") and see what it gives you.

Comment: that only gives me a single column and index of float values. I am assuming this is the target count for my groupings. I can simply use .dropna() after a pivot to get what I need. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do `groupby` and `filter`:

```
# apply function
df1 = df.groupby(['Year','Group1','Group2','Group3']).filter(lambda x: x['Target'].nunique() > 1)

# sort values 
df1 = df1.sort_values('Year').reset_index(drop=True)

print(df1)

    Year Group1 Group2 Group3 Target
0   2015    A     b     X      1
1   2015    A     b     X      0
2   2017    C     d     Z      1
3   2017    C     d     Z      0
```